# Como retornar valor de uma array e de uma subarray?

Tags: php

Boa tarde, minha dúvida é a seguinte:

Possuo uma `array` de gêneros. Código abaixo:

```
$generos = array(
    'filmes' => array(
        1 => 'Ação'
    ), 

    'series' => array(
        1 => 'Artes Marciais'
    ), 

    'animes' => array(
        1 => 'Aventura'
    )
);
```

Necessito retornar essa `array` mostrando todos os códigos dentro dela, exemplo: `ela irá mostrar todos os valores disponíveis dentro de um dos gêneros, vamos supor que você escolheu o gênero: FILMES, é necessário que me retorne todos os valores dentro dessa array`, desse jeito acima não tô sabendo retornar, pois ela tem a array e uma subarray. Eu consigo só retornar os valores completos de uma array quando a `array` está assim:

```
$generos = array('filmes' => 'Ação', 'series' => 'Artes Marciais', 'animes' => 'Aventura');
foreach($generos as $key => $value) {
    echo $value.', ';
}
```

Ai me retorna `Ação, Artes Marciais, Aventura,`, porém quando eu uso subarray como está no primeiro código, não consigo fazer o retorno, gostaria de ajuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faça um segundo foreach assim:

```
$generos = array(
    'filmes' => array(
        1 => 'Ação'
    ), 

    'series' => array(
        1 => 'Artes Marciais'
    ), 

    'animes' => array(
        1 => 'Aventura'
    )
);

foreach($generos as $key => $value) {
    foreach($value as $_key => $subvalue){
       echo $subvalue.', '; 
    }
}
```

Dando echo no key

```
foreach($generos as $key => $value) {
        foreach($value as $_key => $subvalue){
           echo $_key.', '; 
        }
    }
```

Se precisar saber de filmes somente faça assim:

```
foreach($generos['filmes'] as $key => $value) {
        echo $value.', '; 
}


foreach($generos['filmes'] as $key => $value) {
        echo $key.', '; 
}
```

Comment: Nossa, me ajudou demais, grato :D

Comment: Só me tira mais uma dúvida, como faço pra dentro desse mesmo código, ao invés de pegar o valor, pegar a posição, exemplo: 1 = Ação, porém não quero o `Ação`, quero o número `1`, como devo fazer?

Comment: o numero 1 por exemplo so trocar o echo $value pelo echo $key; eu coloquei mais exemplos confira la.

Comment: É eu li, muito obrigado me ajudou demais :D

Comment: Por nada amido ;)